# WCF Streaming and resume options

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming, resume

I have a scenario that I need to implement. Namely, my server needs to implement WCF that would accept large files (500MB - 1GB) and support resuming in case the connection drops for any reason. I was thinking of using WCF streaming for this, but I was wondering if resuming is somehow supported out of the box or do I need to implement custom handling for this.
What is the best course of action for in my case?
Links to examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, i got exactly the same task... How did it turn out for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upload and download methods should accept a parameter that controls the position of download/upload.

I am not sure this is implemented/supported out of the box. The WCF service must have a compatible client for this kind of approach.

**Check this out for complete code.**

http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/09/progress-streamed-file-download-and.html

Other links you might find useful: 
[Chunking Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx) 
[Introduction to Reliable Messaging with the Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx#introtowcfreliablemessaging_topic1)

Comment: This has been very helpful, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.